# Poisson Process Probability of a machine failing before other

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

> Machine $1$ is working now. Machine $2$ will be switched on at time
>   $t$. Suppose that machine $1$ fails at rate $λ_1$ and $2$ at rate
>   $λ_2$with an exponential waiting time. What is the probability that
>   machine $2$ fails first?

**I thought:**

It should be $P(X_2+t<X_1)$ or $P(X_2<X_1|X_2=t)$ but I don't know how to go about calculating it.

Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Calculate the probability M1 fails before time $t$. Once both are working, probability M1<M2 is $\frac {\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}$

Comment: This is definitely $P(X_2+t<X_1)$ (I cannot even fathom what $P(X_2<X_1|X_2=t)$ stands for...) and one knows that, for every nonnegative $x$, $P(X_1>x)=e^{-\lambda_1x}$ hence, by independence, $P(X_1>X_2+t)=E(e^{-\lambda_1(X_2+t)})=e^{-\lambda_1t}E(e^{-\lambda_1X_2})$. Now, can you compute $E(e^{-sX_2})$ for every $s$?

Comment: @A.S. would this be simply $P(X_1>t)P(X_1>X_2)$?

Comment: Yes. I was computing the complementary probability instead. Your answer is coincides with Did's term-for-term.

Comment: @Did I had a think about it, but I don't understand why we are taking expectation? I know how to calculate $E(X_2)=1/\lambda_2$

Comment: Because $P(X_1>X_2+t\mid X_2)=e^{-\lambda_1(X_2+t)}$ and $P(X_1>X_2+t)=E(P(X_1>X_2+t\mid X_2))$. // The missing piece is not $E(X_2)$ but $E(e^{-sX_2})$ (for $s=\lambda_1$), as stated explicitely in my first comment.

Comment: Do I need to put $E(e^{-sX_2})$ back into the probability form to arrive at $P(X_1>X_2)$? I know that $P(X_1>X_2)=$E(e^{-sX_2})$$ which I know how to calculate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_i$ be the failure time of machine $i$. By lack of memory we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X_2+t<X_1) &= \mathbb P(X_1>X_2+t\mid X_1>t)\mathbb P(X_1>t)\\
&= \mathbb P(X_1>X_2)\mathbb P(X_1>t)\\
&= \left(\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}\right) e^{-\lambda_1 t}.
\end{align}